# How to improve the calculation speed of minute OHLC？

Tags: dolphindb

The code provided in the DolphinDB finance example suggests that the MR function in MapReduce is used to improve efficiency.

```
`model=select top 1 symbol,date, minute(time) as minute, open, high, low, last, curVol as volume from quotes where date=2020.06.01,symbol='600000'
if(existsTable("dfs://level2", "minuteBar"))
 db.dropTable("minuteBar")
db.createPartitionedTable(model, "minuteBar", `date`symbol)
def saveMinuteBar(t){
 minuteBar=select first(last) as open, max(last) as high, min(last) as low, last(last) as last, sum(curVol) as volume from t where symbol>='600000', time between 09:30:00.000 : 15:00:00.000 group by symbol, date, minute(time) as minute
 loadTable("dfs://level2", "minuteBar").append!(minuteBar)
 return minuteBar.size()
}
ds = sqlDS(<select symbol, date, time, last, curVol from quotes>)
mr(ds,saveMinuteBar,+)`
```

However, in the actual production, the amount of data is much larger and the progress cannot be viewed. how to improve it？

Answer (score 0):

You can check the progress by querying the output table, such as:

```py
select count(*) from loadTable("dfs://level2", "minuteBar")
select count(*) from loadTable("dfs://level2", "minuteBar") group by date
```